Layout Issue with Tic-Tac-Toe Board Between Mobile Browser Emulation on Desktop and Mobile Browsers
I created a tic-tac-toe game using React and Tailwind CSS. The board layout works as expected when viewed in mobile emulation mode on my desktop browser, as shown in this screenshot. However, when accessed via mobile browsers (Chrome and Safari on iOS), the board appears broken, with horizontal lines shifted to the bottom, as seen in this screenshot .
The goal is to have the board's lines (both vertical and horizontal) properly aligned with rounded edges, regardless of the device.
Code Snippet:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <style>
        @tailwind base;
        @tailwind components;
        @tailwind utilities;

        * {
            font-family: fredoka-medium;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .board {
            display: table;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .board-row {
            display: table-row;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 33%;
        }

        /* Horizontal lines */
        .board-row:not(:last-child)::after {
            border: 4px solid #000;
            border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: -2px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .square {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            position: relative;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 33.33%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        /* Vertical lines */
        /* Vertical lines */
        .square[id="0"]::after,
        .square[id="1"]::after {
            border: 4px solid #000;
            border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: -2px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .square[id="6"]::after,
        .square[id="7"]::after {
            border: 4px solid #000;
            border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: -2px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .square[id="3"]::after,
        .square[id="4"]::after {
            border: 4px solid #000;
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: -2px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        /* css from tailwind */
        .full-viewport {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        .size-full {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .self-center {
            align-self: center;
        }

        .relative {
            position: relative;
        }

        .grid {
            display: grid;
        }

        .grid-rows-12 {
            grid-template-rows: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
        }

        .grid-cols-12 {
            grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
        }

        .row-start-5 {
            grid-row-start: 5;
        }

        .row-end-9 {
            grid-row-end: 9;
        }

        .col-start-2 {
            grid-column-start: 2;
        }

        .col-end-12 {
            grid-column-end: 12;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .md-col-start-5 {
                grid-column-start: 5;
            }

            .md-col-start-5 {
                grid-column-end: 9;
            }

            .md-text-9xl {
                font-size: 8rem;
                line-height: 1;
            }

        }

        .text-7xl {
            font-size: 4.5rem;
            line-height: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="full-viewport grid grid-rows-12 grid-cols-12">
        <div class="size-full self-center relative row-start-5 row-end-9 
    col-start-2 col-end-12 md-col-start-5 md-col-end-9">
            <div class="board">
                <div class="board-row">
                    <button type="button" id="0" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" id="1" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" id="2" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="board-row">
                    <button type="button" id="3" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" id="4" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" id="5" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="board-row">
                    <button type="button" id="6" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" id="7" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" id="8" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>



Questions:
Why does the layout differ between the mobile emulation on a desktop browser and actual mobile browsers?
How can I test mobile browsers more effectively on my desktop to debug this issue?
You can find the full project on GitHub for reference: GitHub Repository.
I added to .board position: relative, which positioned the horizontal lines from the bottom of the viewport to the bottom of the board. I expect the actual mobile page to look like the mobile emulation.

For the display property from the CSS Specification.

The display-internal keywords are defined as follows:
table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-cell, table-column-group, table-column
The element is an internal table element. It generates the appropriate >internal table box which participates in a table formatting context. See >CSS2§17.2 [CSS2].
table-cell boxes have a flow-root inner display type.

The issue is caused by display: table-row, which does not establish a containing block for absolutely positioned children, leading to layout inconsistencies between mobile and desktop environments.
My solution was to add .square's pseudo-element before. Because square has the property display with value table-cell, square generates a block container box, and lays out its contents using flow layout.

flow-root
The element generates a block container box, and lays out
its contents using flow layout. It always establishes a new block
formatting context for its contents. [CSS2]

Here is the new code.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <style>
        @tailwind base;
        @tailwind components;
        @tailwind utilities;

        * {
            font-family: fredoka-medium;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: fredoka-medium;
            src: url(/public/fonts/Fredoka-Medium.ttf);
        }

        .board {
            display: table;
            /* position: relative; */
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .board-row {
            display: table-row;
            width: 100%;
            height: 33%;
        }

        .square {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            position: relative;
            font-family: fredoka-medium;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 33.33%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        /* Horizontal lines */
        .square[id="0"]::before,
        .square[id="3"]::before {
            border: 4px solid #000;
            border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -2px;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .square[id="2"]::before,
        .square[id="5"]::before {
            border: 4px solid #000;
            border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -2px;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .square[id="1"]::before {
            border: 4px solid #000;
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -2px;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .square[id="4"]::before {
            border: 4px solid #000;
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -2px;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        /* Vertical lines */
        .square[id="0"]::after,
        .square[id="1"]::after {
            border: 4px solid #000;
            border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: -2px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .square[id="6"]::after,
        .square[id="7"]::after {
            border: 4px solid #000;
            border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: -2px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .square[id="3"]::after,
        .square[id="4"]::after {
            border: 4px solid #000;
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: -2px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        /* css from tailwind */
        .full-viewport {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        .size-full {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .self-center {
            align-self: center;
        }

        .relative {
            position: relative;
        }

        .grid {
            display: grid;
        }

        .grid-rows-12 {
            grid-template-rows: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
        }

        .grid-cols-12 {
            grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
        }

        .row-start-5 {
            grid-row-start: 5;
        }

        .row-end-9 {
            grid-row-end: 9;
        }

        .col-start-2 {
            grid-column-start: 2;
        }

        .col-end-12 {
            grid-column-end: 12;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .md-col-start-5 {
                grid-column-start: 5;
            }

            .md-col-start-5 {
                grid-column-end: 9;
            }

            .md-text-9xl {
                font-size: 8rem;
                line-height: 1;
            }

        }

        .text-7xl {
            font-size: 4.5rem;
            line-height: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="full-viewport grid grid-rows-12 grid-cols-12">
        <div class="size-full self-center relative row-start-5 row-end-9 
        col-start-2 col-end-12 md-col-start-5 md-col-end-9">
            <div class="board">
                <div class="board-row">
                    <button type="button" id="0" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" id="1" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" id="2" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="board-row">
                    <button type="button" id="3" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" id="4" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" id="5" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="board-row">
                    <button type="button" id="6" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" id="7" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" id="8" class="square text-7xl md-text-9xl"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>



